# define in c get the value of parameter

Tags: c, parameters, c-preprocessor

I want to create a program that will print the value of the three parameter by using define in c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Print(num) printf("%d",n##num)
int main()
{
    int i;
    int n1=1, n2=2, n3=3;
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)Print(i);
}
```

the problem than n##num equal to ni and to n1,n2,n3.
is there a way to get the values of i to set in num instead of "i"?

Comment: Since `i` is not known at preprocessing time, the preprocessor cannot reference the value that `i` will be at the time it's used.

Comment: If you're learning C, it's a good idea to avoid the preprocessor as much as you can. While useful, the preprocessor tends to cause a lot of confusion because the code that you see on the screen isn't quite the code that the compiler sees after the preprocessor is done with it. Write functions instead; you'll learn more and suffer less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preprocessor runs before the code is even compiled.  You can't do loops in the preprocessor like that.

What you really want is an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int n[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    for(i=0;i<3;i++) printf("%d\n", n[i]);
}
```

Comment: Re “The preprocessor runs before the code is even compiled”: [In this example](https://godbolt.org/z/9snrvovqz), why do GCC and Clang report an error for the `{` rather than an error for the `#error` directive?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It seems that if `-E` is passed, only the `#error` directive shows up,

Comment: @EricPostpischil Also, 6.10p6 states: "The implementation can process and skip sections of source files conditionally, include
other source files, and replace macros. These capabilities are called preprocessing,
**because conceptually they occur before translation of the resulting translation unit**." so this would seem to indicate these compilers are non-conforming in this regard.

Comment: The compilers are conforming in this regard. What that word “conceptually” is telling you that the statement is not about how the compiler must execute but about the semantics of C programs. Historically, the preprocessor developed as a separate program, and the name bears that legacy, but it is no longer so in these modern compilers. It is not correct to say the preprocessor runs before the code is even compiled. What is correct is that macro replacement cannot replace variables with their values, so there is no way for `Print(i)` to expand to something with the value of `i`.